# Getting error while passing input parameter in package using cmd

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Below is my command. I have used 5 parameters.

```
dtexec.exe /FILE "D:\Share\CRM#96012 - SSIS Package Live to Tr-28_08_2019\Move_live_to_training_Object\Move_live_to_training_Object\Live_To_Training_Db_Objects.dtsx"
/SET \Package.Variables[User::DesDBName].Properties[Value];"FireTrMJ" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::Password].Properties[Value];"Pnx@2017" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::ServerName].Properties[Value];"192.168.10.157"
/SET \Package.Variables[User::SourceDBName].Properties[Value];"FireLiveMJ" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::UserName].Properties[Value];"sa"
```

I'm getting error as

```
 "/SET \Package.Variables[User::DesDBName].Properties[Value];"FireTrMJ"
 '/SET' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to escape EOL character with `^` in your script

```
dtexec.exe /FILE "D:\Share\CRM#96012 - SSIS Package Live to Tr-28_08_2019\Move_live_to_training_Object\Move_live_to_training_Object\Live_To_Training_Db_Objects.dtsx" ^
/SET \Package.Variables[User::DesDBName].Properties[Value];"FireTrMJ" ^
/SET \Package.Variables[User::Password].Properties[Value];"Pnx@2017" ^
/SET \Package.Variables[User::ServerName].Properties[Value];"192.168.10.157" ^
/SET \Package.Variables[User::SourceDBName].Properties[Value];"FireLiveMJ" ^
/SET \Package.Variables[User::UserName].Properties[Value];"sa"
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working but i get error. I'm trying to pass connection manager details by parameter. But it take default connection manager. give error as " The connection "{4D2FD12E-5E09-41F4-B9A3-E1211171008D}" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found."